How to develop MariaDB custom plugin for Encryption
I am trying to develop a custom MariaDB plugin for encryption.
Here I do not want to store master key on local machine(like file_key_management plugin) , I want to import it from some API.
Any help or source code?
I tried to code it from some references or snippets given in MariaDB docs  but I have not have any proper source code.
it is showing errors for certain undefined keywors , version mismatch
